# How to transfer parameter to fileUpload Jquery?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

There is file input on the page:

```
 <input class="fileupload" data-id="4" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

And Jquery code:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        formData : { client : $(this).attr("data-id"), _token : $('#token').val()},
...
```

I tried to get `data-id` attribute as: `$(this).attr("data-id")`, but can not reach this

Comment: fileupload is an external library. Did you include that library too?

Comment: Yes, I included this library on the page

Comment: Try this: $('.fileupload').attr('data-id');

Comment: I solved this just added attribute in input: ` data-form-data='{"script": "true"}'`